# Keep the formatting when pasting table data in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft

From one of the chats in MS Teams, I'm attempting to copy a table which looks something like below:
[image]

When  copy the entire contents by drag-selecting it and then try to paste that content in another chat window, it loses its formatting and gets pasted as plain text in a single line.

Is there way to tell MS Teams to keep the formatting when copying content?

Comment: Try to paste as a Loop Table.

Comment: @harrymc how does one do that?

Comment: See [Send a Loop component in Teams chat](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-a-loop-component-in-teams-chat-ca5252e7-8201-4490-a6d9-59f20df864c6) (if it applies here).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion. However, that article is useful if I've post a comment. Here I'm trying to copy-paste a comment that someone else has posted